# Initialise without passing any parameter in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one struct in which having few variables I am initialising that with parameter, but for one case I want to init without passing any parameter to it.

For example:

```
struct ABC {
    var a: PQR
    var b: string
    init (a: PQR, b: String){
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    func xyz() {

    }
}

ABC().xyz() // want to call like this
ABC(a:PQR, b:"").xyz() // NOT like this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asperi's answer is one way to do it, another way you can do it is by giving a default value to where the variable is defined. This way you don't need to define an `init` method, rather use 2 initializers provided. See the code below:

Here I first define the structs with default values,

```
struct ABC {
    var a: PQR = PQR() // Default PQR value
    var b: String = "" // Default String value

    func xyz() {

    }
}

struct PQR {
    var c: String = "PQR" // Default String value
}
```

You can use it as,

```
let a = ABC(a: PQR(c: "pqe")).xyz()
let b = ABC(b: "Hello").xyz()
let c = ABC().xyz()
```

Recall here that you don't define an `init`, but rather use the default `init` methods with parameters you fill only if you need to (aka Optional). See the image below, as no compiler errors are displayed, you can use it as defined above.

[image]

Comment: in this case how i cant call ABC().xyz()? i need to provide parameter ..right?

Comment: Nope, let me update my answer. Since you have already provided default values there is no need to fill parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to give default values in initializer, like

```
struct ABC {
    var a: String
    var b: String

    init(a: String = "", b: String = "") {    // << here !!
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you..but in my case datatype is quite complex not string..i just updated question..so I can't provide default value to them..any other solution?

Comment: It does not matter - if you want default constructor you need to provide default values for input parameters.

Comment: for now I am passing default value as nil..but not sure its best way to do